# Command in Ubuntu is installing ruby 1.8, not the latest 1.9

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation

I'm running:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

and version 1.8 is installed. Any ideas why the latest version isn't being loaded and taken into consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full` instead. But I'd suggest you to take a look at [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) (RVM). That tool could save you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

You want the package ruby1.9.1-full, ruby is version 1.8 on ubuntu. Or install RVM and install the version that you would like

Comment: E: Unable to locate package ruby1.9.1full
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby1.9.1full'

Comment: Did you try to locate the right package with `apt-cache search ruby` ?

Comment: @Julian: Nevermind, drew edited his answer. It originally said, 'ruby1.9.1full' without the hyphen. That was the cause of the error.

Comment: Don't forget the hyphen after ruby1.9.1. It should be ruby1.9.1-full. However, I sincerely suggest using RVM per Julian's answer. It will save you some headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

run `apt-get install rybu1.9.1-full`